# Path not get set from crontab

Tags: bash, cron, aix

Very simple and yet not working. Path not get set.

crontab:

```
* * * * * source /home/inst1/.profile; /home/inst1/Scripts/test.sh > /home/inst1/Scripts/test.log 2>&1
```

.profile:

```
[..whatever..]
PATH=/tmp

export PATH
```

test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo $PATH
```

cat to test.log gives me:

```
 /usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/bin
```

I guess it related to AIX environment, but I have no idea - seems simple but I'm missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
* * * * * bash -c "source /home/inst1/.profile; /home/inst1/Scripts/test.sh" > /home/inst1/Scripts/test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the solution & deference (why in my way it's not working)..?

Comment: So what is the equivalent of `source` in `sh`?

Comment: Switching `source` to `.` solved it without the use of `bash -c "..."`.

Comment: Okay, strange. Perhaps a peculiarity of AIX's sh.

Comment: `sh` proper does not know `source`, but if `sh` is actually a link to a shell such as `bash` that does, you can still use `source`. The POSIX equivalent is `.` (just a single period).

Comment: @chepner: thank you. This explains the behavior and [this website](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) is wrong with this sentense: _source is a bourne shell builtin and a POSIX `special' builtin_

Answer (score 0):

`cron` uses `/bin/sh` by default, while `source` is not a POSIX shell command. You need to use `.` instead:

```
* * * * * . /home/inst1/.profile; /home/inst1/Scripts/test.sh > /home/inst1/Scripts/test.log 2>&1
```